# directory.exists() returns false for windows 7 Ultimate N

Tags: java, windows-7

Well, this question refers directly to windows 7.

I run the same code on windows xp and on windows 7.

In windows XP it's true, and in windows 7 it's false!!

```
if (file.exists() || file.getAbsoluteFile().exists())
```

Any ideas?

The URL is to another server where the file is located.

**EDITED**

The user has permission to view/create/delete/edit the directory. I tried from that windows 7 to access by Run option of windows the folder and create another one, and got no permission errors.

The URL is (+-):

```
\\\\myip\\C$\\Devel\\workspace\\project\\HibernateSearch\\indexes
```

**EDITED 2**

I changed the URL to be local on that machine, and now it finds the directory and everything is fine.

What should be the correct URL than for network IP?

Comment: To another server? Are you using smb? HTTP? ..

Comment: I added the url without the real ip

Comment: well its obvious that DIR exists in XP and doesnt in 7

Comment: @kantu: so how do you check if file exists in windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `C$`

I changed the `Devel` directory to be shared in public, and the URL was changed to:

\\myip\Devel\workspace\project\HibernateSearch\indexes (no need to define the drive)

Comment: Makes sense. You can only force a share with C$ if you're an admin. Under UAC your app doesn't have your admin powers unless you ran it elevated.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the win7 machine does not have access to the server where the file is located?
Did you try to access the file from commands line/windows explorer?

Comment: Yes I did. And with no problems!

Answer (score 1):

That is a very uncommon URL format. Maybe MS has fixed something in Win 7 ;-). Try `file://myip/C|/Devel/workspace/project/HibernateSearch/indexes`

Comment: "Uncommon" must be a euphemism for "broken".  The OP's "url" ain't a real URL according to any version of the URL specification.

Comment: When I write: file://myip/C|/Devel/workspace/project/HibernateSearch/indexes JAVA changes it to : file:\\myip\C|\Devel\workspace\project\HibernateSearch\indexes and doesn't find the file!

Comment: This URL does not work for me (as I mentioned in previous comment that JAVA changes the slashes)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Permission problem? Maybe the Win7 user identity can't actually see the file?

Answer (score 0):

Which file are you looking for? If it is a system file / folder, maybe it exists in Windows XP and not in Windows 7.